# How to prevent cursor shift when using `<cmd>` (like `<c-\><c-o>`)?

Tags: key-bindings, cursor-movement

I currently have `inoremap <M-j> <C-\><C-o>gj` in my config but I would like to avoid triggering all `InsertLeave` autocommand when doing this. `inoremap <M-j> <cmd>normal! gj<CR>` works for this, but it behaves incorrectly when the cursor is at the last position of the line in insert mode (just like `<C-o>gj` would).

Any thoughts on how to achieve this on Neovim nightly?

Comment: Define "but it behaves incorrectly when the cursor is at the last position of the line in insert mode".

Comment: @romainl by the correct behavior I mean the same as `<c-\><c-o>gj`.